# how to fetch all the item of a cart by a user in single field of model name orders

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-class-based-views

Right now I'm able to save the data but all the items are saved separately instead of being in one field so how I can achieve that and I using cart as session to save it id and size as a key and value

my models.py where I want to save order

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    status = models.IntegerField(choices = status_choices, default=1)
    method = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False,)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    payment_status = models.IntegerField(choices = payment_status_choices, default=3)
    order_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, default=None) 
    datetime_of_payment = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    

    def placeorder(self):
        self.save()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

my views.py to save the data

and my html where my cart is showing

```
<tbody style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                              {% for item in items %}
                              <tr>
                                <th scope="row">{{forloop.counter}}</th>
                                <td> <img src="{{item.first.url}}" alt="" height="100px"></td>
                                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                                {% if item.swag %}
                                 <td>{{item|cart_size:request.session.cart}}</td>
                                 {% endif %}
                                 {% if not item.swag %}
                                 <td>Regular </td>
                                 {% endif %}
                                <td>{{item.price|currency}}</td>
                                <td> <a href="#">Remove</a> </td>
                              </tr>
                              {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </aside>
            <aside class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="card mb-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group"> <label>Have coupon?</label>
                                <div class="input-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control coupon" name="" placeholder="Coupon code"> <span class="input-group-append"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-apply coupon">Apply</button> </span> </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <dl class="dlist-align">
                            <dt style="float: left; font-size:20px; margin-right:10px;">Total price:</dt>
                            <dd style="font-size: 20px; color:#025;" class="text-right">{{items|total_actual_price:request.session.cart|currency}}</dd>
                        </dl>
                        <dl class="dlist-align">
                            <dt style="float: left; font-size:20px; margin-right:10px;">Discount:</dt>
                            <dd style="font-size: 20px; color:#025;" class="text-right text-danger">{{items|discount_price:request.session.cart|currency}}</dd>
                        </dl>
                        <dl class="dlist-align">
                            <dt style="float: left; font-size:20px; margin-right:10px;">Total Paying Amount:</dt>
                            <dd style="font-size: 20px; color:#025;" class="text-right"><strong name="price" >{{items|total_price:request.session.cart|currency}}</strong></dd>
                        </dl>
                        <hr>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-out btn-primary btn-square btn-main" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"> Make Purchase </a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-out btn-success btn-square btn-main mt-2" data-abc="true">Continue Shopping</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </aside>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see I am using filter to show user total price of his cart so what i want is to save the item id of all the items in items field and size in size field acc to their item and in place of price total price got saved.
But right now it's saving separate field for item, i don't want that

[image: how its look right now]

my html form for checkout and save orders

```
<div class="modal-body">
           <form action="{% url 'orders:checkout' %}" method="Post">
             {% csrf_token %}
             <h3>Please Select Your Payment Method</h3>  <br>
             <div class="method" style="font-size: 23px;">
              <input type="radio" value="postpaid" name="payment" style="height: 20px; width: 20px;">
              <label for="postpaid">Cash On Delivery</label>
              <input type="radio" value="Prepaid" name="payment" style="height: 20px; width: 20px;">
              <label for="prepaid">Online Payment</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn float-right btn-primary" value='Go Ahead'>
        </form>
```

item model

```
class Item(models.Model):
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='our_items')
    subcategories = models.ForeignKey(Subcategories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    contain_size = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='Bagh')
    swag = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=False)
    male = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=False)
    female = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=False)
    unisex = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=False)
    first = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=False)
    second = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=False)
    third = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=True)
    fourth = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=True)
    fifth = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=True)
    sixth = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=True)
    seventh = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=True)
    rate = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=rating, default='⭐⭐⭐⭐')
    stock = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, default='In Stock')
    authentic = models.CharField(max_length=1,blank=False,choices=auth, default='✔')
    price = models.FloatField(blank=False,)
    actual_price = models.FloatField(blank=False)
    type = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=100, default='Cloth')
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,editable=False)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_items_by_id(ids):
        return Item.objects.filter(id__in = ids)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and cart view where all the item goes after selected by a user

```
class Cart(View):
    def get (self, request): 
        cart = request.session.get('cart', None)
        if not cart:
            cart = {}
        request.session['cart'] = cart
        ids = (list(cart.keys()))
        ids = (list(request.session.get('cart').keys()))
        item = Item.get_items_by_id(ids)
        address = Address.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        print(item)
        return render(request, 'cart.html', {'items': item, 'addresses':address })
```

[image]

It does save the item in it but I want to fetch all the items of the car in that field

```
adding updated model as told



      class Order(models.Model):
    status_choices = (
        (1, 'PENDING'),
        (2, 'CONFIRMED'),
        (3, 'PACKED'),
        (4, 'SHIPPED'),
        (5, 'IN WAY'),
        (6, 'ARRIVED DESTINATION'),
        (7, 'RECIEVED'),
        (8, 'COMPLETED')
    )
    payment_status_choices = (
        (1, 'SUCCESS'),
        (2, 'FAILURE' ),
        (3, 'PENDING'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, default= True, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    status = models.IntegerField(choices = status_choices, default=1)
    method = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False,)
    total_price = models.FloatField(blank=False, default=0)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    payment_status = models.IntegerField(choices = payment_status_choices, default=3)
    order_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200, null=True, default=None) 
    datetime_of_payment = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    # related to razorpay
    razorpay_order_id = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    razorpay_payment_id = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    razorpay_signature = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.order_id is None and self.datetime_of_payment and self.id:
            self.order_id = self.datetime_of_payment.strftime('CODER%Y%m%dODR') + str(self.id)
            return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + " " + str(self.order_id) + " " + str(self.created_at)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    size = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=False)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.order.order_id
```

updated views.py

```
class Checkout(View):
def post (self, request,):
    user = request.user
    address = Address.objects.filter(default=True, user=request.user)
    cart = request.session.get('cart')
    items = Item.get_items_by_id(list(cart.keys()))
    prefer = request.POST.get('payment')
    total_price = request.POST.get('paying_price')
    total_price = json.loads(total_price)

    with transaction.atomic():
        order = Order.objects.create(
                user=user,
                total_price=total_price,
                address=address.first(),
                method = prefer,
                )
        for item in items:
            item_order = OrderItem.objects.create(
                order=order,
                item=item,
                size=cart.get(str(item.id)),
                price=item.price,
            )
        request.session['cart'] = {}
    return redirect('orders:cart',)
```

adding the traceback

Environment:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/Check-Out/

Django Version: 3.2.6
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'crispy_forms',
 'xhtml2pdf',
 'accounts',
 'products',
 'orders']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy\coolbuy\orders\views.py", line 61, in post
    item_order = OrderItem.objects.create(
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 453, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 682, in save
    self._prepare_related_fields_for_save(operation_name='save')
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 932, in _prepare_related_fields_for_save
    raise ValueError(

Exception Type: ValueError at /Check-Out/
Exception Value: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'order'.
```

Comment: You mean, You don't want orders in different field ?

Comment: @PrOgRaMmEr yes i mean if a person create an order all the items of that order goes in a single field instead of creating sepreate field for every single item in that order

Comment: first of all it would be better if you can split the model. One for the order and one for the order items. that way you will have only one row for the order.

Comment: are you suggesting me to create two different model name order and orders item

Comment: Could you post the code for Item model as well?

Comment: @OmarSiddiqui added

Comment: seems that my bounty will expire and no one can anwser it

Comment: the way you implement the views is wrong, you should do the loop `` for item in items:``` after creating the order, because 1 order, contains multiple OrderItem, check my answer again below. 
And in your new model is not exactly the way I told you about the model relations, as well as the views. look again! you should delete the ```order``` field from ```ProductOrder```,  and add ```product_order = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem, related_name='order', null=True)``` to model ```OrderItem``` and don't forget to make migration and migrate

Comment: @Diand yeah thats my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in most of the answers, you have to split the models into 2. The Order-OrderItem scenario is a good example for One-to-Many relationship.

Consider you ordering Roti, Paneer (Indian dishes) and Coke from Swiggy (Indian food delivery app). Swiggy says that your order id is #123456.

The models should look like this.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices = status_choices, default=1)
    method = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False,)
    ... other fields ...
```

The Order model tells that the Order is placed by the user Shreyas, method of payments is X and current status is this.

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    size = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=False)
    ... any other fields ...
```

OrderItem model tells that the this item - Coke - is part of Order ID #123456 and the price at the time of ordering is Rs.X.

Your database after saving should look like this -

#### Order table

| id | user | method | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | shreyas (id) | payment | order_placed |

#### OrderItem table

| id | order_id | item_id | size | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456 | roti (id) | n | 10.00 |
| 2 | 123456 | paneer (id) | n | 50.00 |
| 3 | 123456 | coke (id) | n | 25.00 |

## Saving your order

There is a `with transaction.atomic` statement in the code, this allows you to write all the models in one go, and revert if any of the write statements fail. Ref: [Django transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/transactions/)

```
class Checkout(View):
    def post (self, request):
        user = request.user
        address = Address.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        cart = request.session.get('cart')
        total_price = request.POST.get('price') 
        items = Item.get_items_by_id(list(cart.keys()))
        prefer = request.POST.get('payment')

        with transaction.atomic:
          order = Order.objects.create(
                user=user,
                date_of_payment=datetime.datetime.now(),
                total_price=total_price,
                address=address
              )

          for item in items:
              prod_order = OrderItem.objects.create(
                order=order
                item=item,
                size=item.size,
                price=price,
            )
   ... return the view ...
```

Comment: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'order'. it throws the error

Comment: Your updated model is not as per my definition. My definition treats the relationship as One-to-Many, yours treats it as Many-to-Many that will make a difference. Please update as per my definition and try.

Comment: i already change that to foriegn key and update my model here now have look

Comment: indentaion is right in the model please don't mind there

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the model `Order` in two models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices = status_choices, default=1)
    method = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False,)
    payment_status = models.IntegerField(choices = payment_status_choices, default=3)
    order_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, default=None) 
    datetime_of_payment = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

    def placeorder(self):
        self.save()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class ProductOrder(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeingKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=False)
```

In that way you will have 1-Order and Many-Productos per Order.

Comment: so how can i save cart item in this product order model and all the other thing in my order model

Answer (score 0):

adding the answer from @allexiusw

The best practice for this is, you need to create 2 models with many to many relationship for product_order:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    product_order = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem, related_name='order', null=True)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(default=0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, null=True)
    datetime_of_payment = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)
    ...
   

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=True)
    ...
```

To save it to that 2 models, you can do something like this:

```
class Checkout(View):
    def post (self, request):
        user = request.user
        address = Address.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        cart = request.session.get('cart')
        total_price = request.POST.get('price') 
        items = Item.get_items_by_id(list(cart.keys()))
        prefer = request.POST.get('payment')


        order = Order.objects.create(
                user=user,
                date_of_payment=datetime.datetime.now(),
                total_price=total_price,
                address=address)

        for item in items:
            prod_order = OrderItem.objects.create(
                item=item,
                size=item.size,
                price=price,
            )
            order.product_order.add(prod_order)
        order.save()
        ....
```

Comment: instead of creating order it throws error NOT NULL constraint failed: orders_orderitem.order_id

Comment: As your witten answer

Comment: im editing the answer, don't forget  to add ```null=True``` to all field specially if you adding new field. and don't forget to ```makemigrations``` and ```migrate``` after make a model changes... @Shreyash

Comment: I see your latest update, in your new model is not exactly the way I told you about the model relations, as well as the views. look again! you should delete the ```order``` field from ```ProductOrder```,  and add ```product_order = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem, related_name='order', null=True)``` to model ```OrderItem```

Comment: it throws error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add' and one thing i can not use many to many field i have to use foriegn key

Comment: of course, it will throw an error. you're adding ```item_order``` into a field that doesn't even exist. Add ```order_item = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem, related_name='order', null=True)``` into your Order model. you cannot achieve this unless you use Manytomany fields. ```order.order_item.add(item_order)``` is adding OrderItem instance into your Order.

Comment: I don't even understand why you cant use many-to-many fields.

Comment: Order: Shreyash None None>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used. this eror is thowing when using many to many field

Comment: you don't need ```order_id = models.CharField``` on your older model, the ```id``` field is already on every model by default, even if you didn't put it on the models, and you should not use CharField for order_id / pk.

Comment: order_id is id for payment gateway integration

Comment: i want to randomly generate order id for every order

Comment: You're not implementing the code as recommended, you also said that it throwing an error but you don't even update your code, and not specify the error, it's very hard to give you help this way.

Comment: Updated have a look

Comment: the ```order.order_item.add(item_order)``` indentation is wrong, should be inside the loop. add 1 indentation

Comment: item got save but order not created

Comment: <Order: Shreyash None None>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used. this is the error

Comment: add ```order_group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)``` to your ```Order``` model.

Comment: i did add done mikemigrations but when i  try to migrate it again throw error foreign key mismatch - "orders_order_order_item" referencing "orders_order"

Comment: and now i am unable to migrate

Comment: remove all the files in the migrations folder except the init file, and then makemigration migrate

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have experience with e-commerce,
as much i have understand that you want to save all the details of item like size , price , name ,mail description in one single field .Is that right ?

if yes , then I think directly it's not possible you can try one thing --

```
1.You can take all the desired data and create a dictionary or list out of them
2. Create a single textfield with more maxlength and a FK with user or customer model  and then you can save the list or dict as text in that one field in db, and then can retrieve the all data as well as you can get by index also.\
```

But it will be more efficient for storing data only , if you want to retrieve the data efficiently then go for separate models as you have created.

hope it will have, I have applied same type of concept to store customer complain and payment details of users and I like your code , you are following good practice!

Comment: i also thought that thing but i guess that not a good way for view order so i am looking f for better and clean method